# App URL to project URL

Tags: django, django-urls

I have a django project in production, only including a single app at the moment. Let's say my domain is `myproject.com` and my app is called `myapp`. I want the index to be `myproject.com/` not `myproject.com/myapp/`.

This is how my `myproject/urls.py` looks like:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),
...
```

And `myapp.urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('myapp.views',
url(r'^$', 'about'),
...
```

How can I make the app available under myproject.com? Or is that something you should be doing by a re-direct, e.g. in your .htaccess?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to redefine your `urls.py` to this

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', include('myapp.urls')),
...
```

This will capture all calls to '/'.

This will enable all your urls from the "root".
Then of course you have to write your `myapp.urls` so that they make sense when
put in a webbrowser.

**UPDATE**

So after a big ol' chat: this is the thing I think you want pure codewise

in your root `urls.py`

```
url(r'', include('myapp.urls')),
```

in your myapp.urls

```
urlpatterns = patterns('myapp.views',
    url(r'^$', 'first_view'),
    url(r'^evilCellphones/$', 'another_view'),
)
```

What essentially happens here is that you include your `myapp.urls` to no
namespace but since Django still loads it it'll include your newly defined urls.
From there you can redefine all of your urls and have them get obey the same name
space as "myproject".

[This part of the docs are explains it really well](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#multiple-view-prefixes)

Comment: I get the implications...So you think its better to use a re-direct, e.g. in your .htaccess?

Comment: It all depends on how you're planning on going forward with your project. If you're planning on adding multiple apps then, maybe, otherwise this is fine.

Comment: In my myapp.urls.py, everything that isn't the index should be matched liked this? `^$/contact`

Comment: Almost, it should be something like this: `(r'^contact/$', 'myapp.view.some_magical_pony_view')`. You don't want doubleslashes in your url. Unfortunately, I can't test this for you atm but will verify in ~30 mins :)

Comment: I really don't get how the two url.py files work together. In my understanding one is project wide and the other defines the urls for your app. So `(r'^contact/$'...` finds everything under the ROOT of contact. But if contact is a `html` this won't work, right?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean with a `html` but essentially you're correct and basically, what you're doing, when having two different `urls.py` is just tidying the urls up. the call to `include()` makes the myapp-urls "global", did it make sense?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25353/discussion-between-larsvegas-and-limelights)