# Django can't get root url for my app

Tags: python, django

I have made an "app" that should be the frontpage for my project but when I try to use it as the root for my project like this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` it gives me a 404. When I, however put it as a sub folder `http://127.0.0.1:8000/frontpage/` it works. This is my urls.py files:

#### project/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    url(r'^/', include('frontpage.urls')),
    url(r'^s/', include('django.contrib.flatpages.urls')),
    url(r'^kalender/', include('events.urls')),
    #url(r'^kontakt/',    include('envelope.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^adminfiles/', include('adminfiles.urls')), )
```

#### frontpage/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from frontpage import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153678/app-url-to-project-url/15153836#15153836 - might perhaps be of help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
url(r'^', include('frontpage.urls', namespace="frontpage")),


urlpatterns = patterns('frontpage.views',
    url(r'^$', 'index', name='index'),
)
```

Comment: It worked great! Very thankfull! Can you tell me why my solution didn't work? For me this seems just to be another way to do the same thing as I did?

Comment: First of all you put '/' in url(r'^/', include('frontpage.urls')). Second is your using namespace in frontpage urls.py so you need also to define namespace in the main urlconf